# Determine if the Time is between the t1 and t2 with database

Tags: vb.net

i want to determine if the time in combobox is between my start time and end time  and date using datetimepicker whenever i start the program it says table reserve is already open by other user

here is my code:

```
Sub checkingsched()
    cn.Close()
    cn.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM mechanics Where Mechanic_ID = " & cmbmechanic.Text & ";", cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If (dr.Read()) = True Then
        dt.Clear()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Start_Time, End_Time, DateR  FROM Reserve where Mechanic_ID = " & cmbmechanic.Text & ";", cn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        cn.Close()
        Dim st As Date = (Format(("Start_Time"), "Short Time"))
        Dim et As Date = (Format(("End_Time"), "Short Time"))
        Dim dtt As Date = (Format(DateTime.Today, "Short Date"))
        Dim dtp As Date = (Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "Short Date"))
        Dim tm As Date = (Format(DateTime.Today, "Short Time"))

        If cmbtos.Text = (tm.Ticks >= et.Ticks And tm.Ticks <= st.Ticks) And dtp = (dr(dt.Rows(0)("DateR"))) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot Reserve in this time. Mechanics is on reserve in that time or working that time")
            itemsoftos()


        End If
        cn.Close()



    End If
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Because MS-SQL (and others) has a `between` expression that is suited for this: `where [DateField] between 'StartDate' and 'EndDate'` - although it sounds like you might be asking why you're getting a table in use error? What's the question?

Comment: With all those `cn.Open()` and `cn.Close()` statements and no sign of a `cn.Dispose()`, you should expect problems. Instead, create the connection variable only when and where you need to use it with a `Using` statement. The corresponding `End Using` will take care of disposing of the connection cleanly and automatically.